# Image Buttons that user can only select one of JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, textfield

I'm working on a **Mood Journal app** and at the moment, it asks the user to rate their mood on a scale of 1-5 before saving their entry as shown on the image below.

I want to replace this with 5 small buttons laid out horizontally with respective emoji images as their background. I already have chosen the images I would like to use, and I looked into implementing a normal FX Button or an `ImageView`, but with those it appears that clicking the button simply does some action; rather, I want the user to only be able to select one at a time (like a Radio Button). How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: How it will be shown that only one is selected ? For example the background color of the Button will be different?

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned that. I was thinking maybe a thin outline around the button to show which one was last clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion 1:**

You can use ControlsFX [SegmentedButton](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/SegmentedButton.html)(Set as the graphic of the button you preferred emoji):

[image]

From the doc:

> The `SegmentedButton` is a simple control that forces together a group of ToggleButton instances such that they appear as one collective button (with sub-buttons), rather than as individual buttons. This is better clarified with a picture:

There is very little API on this control, you essentially create `ToggleButton` instances as per usual (and don't bother putting them into a `ToggleGroup`, as this is done by the `SegmentedButton` itself), and then you place these buttons inside the buttons list. The long-hand way to code this is as follows:

```
 ToggleButton b1 = new ToggleButton("day");
 ToggleButton b2 = new ToggleButton("week");
 ToggleButton b3 = new ToggleButton("month");
 ToggleButton b4 = new ToggleButton("year");  

 SegmentedButton segmentedButton = new SegmentedButton();    
 segmentedButton.getButtons().addAll(b1, b2, b3, b4);
```

A slightly shorter way of doing this is to pass the ToggleButton instances into the varargs constructor, as such:

```
SegmentedButton segmentedButton = new SegmentedButton(b1, b2, b3, b4);
```

**Suggestion 2:**

You can use ControlsFX [Rating](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Rating.html) :

[image]

From the docs:

A control for allowing users to provide a rating. This control supports partial ratings (i.e. not whole numbers and dependent upon where the user clicks in the control) and updating the rating on hover.

To create a Rating control that looks like this is simple:

```
final Rating rating = new Rating();
```

This creates a default horizontal rating control. To create a vertical Rating control, simply change the orientation, as such:

```
final Rating rating = new Rating();
 rating.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
```

You can continue reading from the [doc](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Rating.html)...

---

**Suggestion 3:(No Third Library Needed)**

You can make a custom [ToolBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToolBar.html) with 5 `Button` , each one will have a PseudoClass(`selected`) and every time one of them is pressed the others will have the Pseudoclass(`selected=false`) , so the user can see which one is selected.

So you can make something similar to : [image]

Read this article if you want to implement it -> http://fxexperience.com/2012/02/customized-segmented-toolbar-buttons/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: I'd rather use a Pseudo class instead of a class – this seems to be what they are made for…

Comment: @glglgl Ops yes that what I wanted to mean Pseudo class, I am fixing it.

Comment: @JoshNarsu Glad it helped :-)